# Publishing Chrome Extension using Chrome Dev Editor

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, chrome-dev-editor

I am trying to publish a sample chrome extension using the Chrome Dev editor, but once I click on the "Publish To Chrome Web Store" option I get redirected to a Google Login page in Chrome. 
After logging-in, nothing happens after that.

Am I doing anything wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too. The Dev Editor is not totally deprecated but it is no longer in active development. https://plus.google.com/+SriramSaroop/posts/6EwgknwKpeS

Unfortunately it seems that we need to take the more involved steps here: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish